# Network Connection working, no internet

Tags: internet

Installed Elementary 6.1 on Lenovo Ideapad, worked fine for 2 days.  Booted up from sleep and connects to home network (wired and wireless) fine, but no internet (browser or system updates) can ping 8.8.8.8 from terminal.  Router shows internet connected. Other home devices connect fine.  No apps added or deleted immediately prior to loss of internet connection.

What am I missing?

Comment: So obviously this is a DNS issue, but why only on one machine?  Thinking AF changing DNS at the router to open DNS, thoughts?

Comment: Same problem here, new installation on computer. Worked fine at first but after reboot no internet. Using a wired connection. DNS is assigned, ping ok. What can cause this issue and how to solve?